# Bootstrap tagsinput Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tagsinput is not a function

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-tags-input

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo" data-role="tagsinput">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="/bower_components/admin-lte/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput-angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("document").ready(function () {
        $('input').tagsinput('add', 'some tag');

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

its because of app.js file but idk why and how to resolve it. when i remove app.js it works fine but i need that for other functionalities.

Comment: How about `$('input').attr('some-tag', 'Tag value');`

Comment: That tells you that the `bootstrap-tagsinput` plugin did not load or initialize properly. Check your network tab: are you sure the plugin's JS files are being loaded correctly?

Comment: yes they are loaded correctly and it works if i comment app.js file.@Terry but i need that file too for some other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that with app.js i was using defer. i removed it and it works fine.